# Apache 2.4 redirection from load-balanced reverse-proxy not working but working in non-load-balanced reverse-proxy

Tags: apache, next.js, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have 2 NextJS internal servers/applications that is reverse-proxied by Apache 2.4. Let's have the 2 internal servers as `http://internal:3000/foo` and `http://internal:3001/foo` and the external URL as `http://external/foo`.

When the NextJS is accessed on the base path (i.e. `http://internal:3000/foo`), it will be redirected to `http://internal:3000/foo/bar/baz` on `HTTP Code 308`. So over the reverse-proxy, I expected the same, that the redirection will happen from `http://external/foo` to `http://external/foo/bar/baz`.
The config in `next.config.js` is as follow

```
...
module.exports = {
  ...
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/bar/baz',
        permanent: true
      }
    ]
  },
  basePath: 'foo'
}
```

What happen is that this redirection works perfectly when I tried reverse-proxy to only 1 NextJS application **without load balancing**, e.g. I only reverse proxy to `http://internal:3000/foo`.
The config that I used is as follow

```
<Location "/foo">
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:3000/foo"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:3000/foo"
</Location>
```

But the redirection does *not* work when I tried reverse-proxy to 2 NextJS application **on load balancing**.
The config that I used is as follow

```
<Proxy "balancer://example">
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:3000/foo"
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:3001/foo"
</Proxy>

<Location "/foo">
    ProxyPass "balancer://example"
    ProxyPassReverse "balancer://example"
</Location>
```

What happen instead is that it will keep redirecting from `http://external/foo` to `http://external/foo` i.e. infinite redirect that result in `TOO_MANY_REDIRECT`.

It baffles me that the redirection works in non load-balancing scenario but failed when using load-balancing. Any ideas what is actually happening? Is there response header being written that I am unaware of when using proxy load-balancing? Thanks!

**Update/progress (1):**

I suspect there is rewriting happening in `mod_proxy_balancer.c` in following section

```
    access_status = rewrite_url(r, *worker, url);
    /* Add the session route to request notes if present */
    if (route) {
        apr_table_setn(r->notes, "session-sticky", sticky);
        apr_table_setn(r->notes, "session-route", route);


        /* Add session info to env. */
        apr_table_setn(r->subprocess_env,
                       "BALANCER_SESSION_STICKY", sticky);
        apr_table_setn(r->subprocess_env,
                       "BALANCER_SESSION_ROUTE", route);
    }
    ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_DEBUG, 0, r, APLOGNO(01172)
                  "%s: worker (%s) rewritten to %s",
                  (*balancer)->s->name, (*worker)->s->name, *url);


    return access_status;
```

which can be found in `https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/317108ee6e84ae47bd0f6121e3a64074c5d68c7b/modules/proxy/mod_proxy_balancer.c#L631-L647`

**Update/progress (2):**

I turned on `mod_dumpio` to log all the incoming and outgoing traffic into and from apache, and have confirmed that there is indeed a rewriting happening.

The rewriting is happening as follow:

1. `GET /foo`, which is the original request sent to the external server.
2. `GET /foo/`, which is the request sent to the internal server. Notice there is rewriting of adding slash at the end.
3. `Location /foo`, which is the internal server's redirection response location. This is an intended location because in internal server, `GET /foo/` will be redirected to `Location /foo` while `GET /foo` will be redirected to `Location /foo/bar/baz`. Under normal circumstances the redirection will be handled by the internal server, meaning that `GET /foo/` will result in redirection resulting in `GET /foo`, eventually yielding `Location /foo/bar/baz` but this does not happen in reverse-proxy.
4. `Location /foo`, which is the external server's redirection response location. Because (4) and (1) is the same URL, therefore it will create a redirection loop.

With the rewriting confirmed, now I am looking whether there is way to solve this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the issue, and pertaining to the 2nd update above, I managed to find where the "rewriting" happen which helped me fix the issue.

---

`tl;dr`
The fix is basically moving the path from `BalancerMember` to the balancer itself, i.e.

```
<Proxy "balancer://example/foo"> // used to be "balancer://example"
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:3000" // used to be "http://localhost:3000/foo"
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:3001" // used to be "http://localhost:3001/foo"
</Proxy>

// change to point to the balancer accordingly
<Location "/foo">
    ProxyPass "balancer://example/foo"
    ProxyPassReverse "balancer://example/foo"
</Location>
```

---

As for my finding, the "rewriting" is not so much of rewriting but is actually URL canonicalisation performed by Apache, in `mod_proxy_balancer` or `mod_proxy_http` modules (or depends on your scheme). [example of canonicalisation source code in mod_proxy_balancer](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/b27e4462585c135b155d606a5e4a2479d4074cf8/modules/proxy/mod_proxy_balancer.c#L113)

Changing `balancer://example -> balancer://example/foo` makes its URL scheme structure wise same to `http://localhost:3000/foo`, which when undergoing canonicalisation will not yield trailing slash at the end, which is caused by `balancer://example` not having path right after the "host", and therefore with the said change the behaviour for reverse-proxy using either load balancer or not will finally be the same.